# Why HTML5 Boilerplate makes bower saving dependencies on public/components

Tags: bower, html5boilerplate

I'm starting a project using a fresh download of html5bp. 
I'm using bower for dependency management. However, the dependencies are being saved at public/components, instead of the classic bower_components. I want them to be saved on bower_components as usual by default. I din´t find any bower.rc, or any configuration that changes the default behavior.
Could you help me understanding why this is happening?

Thks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I´ve figured out the problem. There was a .bowerrc file in the root directory. Thanks anyway.